# Cannot Update Rich Text on Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, actiontext

I have a model called blog that has a rich text field. There are no issues when I create a new blog post.

But when I try to update an existing blog post, the rich text content does not get updated. But the title and image are updated and rails shows now errors.

So, how do I solve this.

Blogs/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@blog) do |f| %>
<div class="space" style=" margin-bottom: 20px;">
Company: <%= f.check_box :company %>
</div>
  <div class="space">
    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Name", style: "width: 100%;background-color: white;   padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" %>
  </div>
  <div class="space">
    <%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: "Description", style: "width: 100%;background-color: white;   padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" %>
  </div>
  <div class="space" style="">
    <%= f.rich_text_area :content, style: "min-height: 500px;" %>
  </div>

  <div class="space ">
    <label class=" button" style="color: #20B2AA; Background-color: white; width: auto; border: solid 1px #20B2AA;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;"id="tasklink">
  + Add Image
         <span style="display:none;">
            <%= f.file_field :image, class: "custom-file-input", onchange: "javascript:updateList()", id: "file" %>
        </span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="fileList" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
  <script>
    updateList = function() {
      var input = document.getElementById('file');
      var output = document.getElementById('fileList');

      output.innerHTML = '<ul>';
      for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
        output.innerHTML += '<li>' + input.files.item(i).name + '</li>';
      }
      output.innerHTML += '</ul>';
    }
  </script>



  <div class="button2">
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn button", style: "min-width: 25%; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 1.25em; margin-top:25px;" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Blogs/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@blog) do |f| %>
<div class="space" style=" margin-bottom: 20px;">
Company: <%= f.check_box :company %>
</div>
  <div class="space">
    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Name", style: "width: 100%;background-color: white;   padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" %>
  </div>
  <div class="space">
    <%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: "Description", style: "width: 100%;background-color: white;   padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" %>
  </div>
  <div class="space" style="">
    <%= f.rich_text_area :content, style: "min-height: 500px;" %>
  </div>

  <div class="space ">
    <label class=" button" style="color: #20B2AA; Background-color: white; width: auto; border: solid 1px #20B2AA;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;"id="tasklink">
      + Add Image
         <span style="display:none;">
        <%= f.file_field :image, class: "custom-file-input", onchange: "javascript:updateList()", id: "file" %>
        </span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="fileList" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
  <script>
    updateList = function() {
      var input = document.getElementById('file');
      var output = document.getElementById('fileList');

      output.innerHTML = '<ul>';
      for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
        output.innerHTML += '<li>' + input.files.item(i).name + '</li>';
      }
      output.innerHTML += '</ul>';
    }
  </script>



  <div class="button2">
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn button", style: "min-width: 25%; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 1.25em; margin-top:25px;" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

config/routes.rb

```
  resources :blog, controller: "blogs" do
      resources :blogcomments
  end
  resources :blogs

  get '/blog', :to => 'blogs#index'
```

Blogs_controller.rb

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [:create, :new, :update, :edit]

  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)
    if @blog.save
      redirect_to blog_path(@blog)
    end
  end

  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
  end

  def show
    @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @title = @blog.title
    if @blog.description
      @description = @blog.description
    end
    @blogs = Blog.all.order('created_at DESC')
    @blogcomment = Blogcomment.new
    @blogcomments = @blog.blogcomments
  end

  def edit
    @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @blog  = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if @blog.update_attributes(blog_params)
      redirect_to blog_path(@blog)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @title = "Quantatask Blog"
    @description = "The oficial Quantatask blog. Find tips on how to learn to code and on how to start freelancing."
    @blogs = Blog.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4).order('created_at DESC')
  end

  private

    def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :description, :content, :company, :image)
    end
end
```

models/blog.rb

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :content
  has_one_attached :image
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
  has_many :blogcomments
end
```

Comment: @max I know I had originally written it like that. someone edited my post to make it appear as such

Comment: @max I'll edit it back

Comment: Ok, I apologize as it was caused by a bad edit.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong here. Did you check the incoming parameters in the log?

Comment: @max Blog Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE "blogs" SET "title" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "blogs"."id" = ?  [["title", "Best Freelance Websites for Developer"], ["updated_at", "2020-07-06 15:10:54.723406"], ["id", 5]]  Only the name seems to be updated and not the content

Comment: Thats the SQL query, check the parameters sent from the browser to rails to see if it's a Trix issue.